# Automate downloading a file from a browers every 30mins

Tags: macros, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler

I want to setup a automated task (marco) where every 30 mins ( between 9-5pm mon- friday),  download a .csv report.  The task I want done is to login to a  website and make 2-3 sections to download the report.

I haven't done anything like this before, but I thought I could set up a macro and windows task scheduler, But this macro guide starts off saying "Caution - Do not save passwords or other sensitive information in macros."

https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/4052290/accessories-how-do-i-create-macros

Comment: You'd have a better time using Python to download that file. It's easy, if you know how to program. If you like, I can program you a small script and show you how to use it. http://www.python.org

Comment: I haven't done proper programming in a decade,  and that was simple stuff.  How would I just the script to run every 30mins? windows task manager?

Comment: Though I don't know much about macros, I can't imagine the security implications being any different storing credentials in a macro than in a python script

Comment: @PaddyD, to run the script, you'd just need to setup a new task using Task Scheduler, which would run the command line argument `python3 C:\Path\To\myScript.py`.  It'd be a simple as 1) download python 2) make the script 3) configure Task Scheduler